# How do I explain to my boss that a coworker isn't capable?

Tags: communication, project-management, colleagues, time-management, stress

So I have this giant project that has a ticking deadline of a little under 2 months. My boss (IMO) over promised on the timeline to the client by a mile and let the client set the deadline rather than the amount of work. About a month ago he hired another dev to help me out realizing I couldn't possibly do all the work myself. I'm already pulling regular 10 hour days.

The guy he hired is just a mess though. On friday we were supposed to have an internal demo ready however when I started going over things with my partner on thursday it became glaringly clear he didn't have even a fraction of his work done.

On friday I came in a few hours early and started working on all his stuff and when he got there we worked together the rest of the day trying to catch up. However it became more and more clear as I worked with him that he doesn't know his stuff beyond the very basics of javascript.

In the afternoon I had other things I really needed to get done and asked him if he felt comfortable implementing the rest on his own and he blatantly said he didn't know where to begin and that I'd done in a few hours what took him almost 2 weeks to do.

I've tried bringing this all up with my boss and point blank told him that I don't see us making the deadline. He doesn't seem to be open to the input though and has now insisted that I just go over my partners work every morning and evening to see what he's done. I can understand that he probably doesn't have time to look for and hire another dev but am running myself ragged trying to manage everything. We can't make the deadlines he's setting and I don't know how to tell him that just because he wants it done by a certain date doesn't mean its possible. Especially with my limited time and my partners limited knowledge.

Comment: Is the important part here "my partner isn't capable" or "we're not going to make the deadline"? They might be related, but they're different things.

Comment: "Grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change, the courage to change the things I can, and the wisdom to know the difference" There is a lot in your question that refers to things other people are doing. A symptom of bad management is a boss who leaves problems for others to solve. You can't help the new co-worker, help your boss and help yourself at the sametime. I would recommend that you focus on the top priorities of problems that you can actually resolve, and just take it one day at a time. The project failing isn't the same as you failing. Try not to see it that way.

Answer (score 5):

"I don't know how to tell him". For example: "Hey boss, there is no way we can hit this deadline". You can add "I have been working overtime for four weeks, and I'm tiring out, so you can't expect much from me. And my new colleague doesn't produce any useful work at all. If you want to hit this deadline, then you get me one or better two people who are really qualified to do this job".

Telling your boss as early as possible is really important. Not hitting the deadline will cost your company and your boss. The earlier he or she knows about it, the better are the chances that the damage can be limited.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your boss fully informed, and stop doing your colleagues work for him; when (not if) you miss the deadline, it shouldn't be because you didn't do your own work.